# Simple uniqueness conditions for integro-differential

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, integro-differential-equations

Let $h:\mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R} $.

Consider the following integro-differential equation: $$g'(t)=\int_0^t h(t,g(t),g(z))\;dz $$

With initial condition $g(0)=0$, is a unique solution for $g:[0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ implied by the continuity of $h$?

---

Thoughts: Seems like the needed condition is for the RHS to be Lipschitz. That way, I think the usual results should carry over and a unique solution should exist. Not exactly sure how the integral affects the problem.

Edit 1: I think it is probably necessary to assume that $h$ is Lipschitz or at least Lipschitz in the second argument to assure a Lipschitz condition on the RHS. Is this sufficient for uniqueness?

Comment: You have no other hypothesis on $h$?

Comment: I guess that it will probably be necessary to assume that $h$ is lipschitz in the second argument since the RHS cannot be lipschitz otherwise. Is this what you are asking about? I think that I can assume this.